# MapBox - Uber-like location picker

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to make an Uber-like location picker with MapBox. I would like to 'freeze' map on fixed marker (that's in center of the map) when zooming.

By default, whenever you zoom, map is actually zooming to the click/pinch point where you started the zoom rather than to map center. I almost got it but now I'm battling the centering transition (I don't want it).

Is there any trick to achieve that? Currently I'm trying to work with mapbox events `zoomend` and `move`. Unfortunately `zoom` throws too many events and the map is lagging like hell:

```
let markerLocation = map.getCenter();

const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
  .setLngLat(markerLocation)
  .addTo(map);

map.on(`zoomend`, (e) => {
  map.flyTo({
    center: markerLocation,
  });
});

map.on(`move`, (e) => {
  if (map.isZooming()) {
    return;
  }
  markerLocation = map.getCenter();
  marker.setLngLat(markerLocation);
});
```

Please find the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pawelol/kpu8nzh9/2/

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Found option from documentation that does it just right. 
```scrollZoom: {around: "center"}
touchZoomRotate: {around: 'center'}```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwv0e6nr/21/